# Making SVG respond to mouse over events, but allow clickthrough to other elements

Tags: html, css, svg, mouseevent, z-index

I have an animated SVG of a node map that follows the cursor when a user hovers over it. I've animated it using Javascript and it works beautifully, however it's supposed to be a background element, which causes a problem:

If the svg is behind the buttons in the footer (where it is located), then the mouseover events wont fire. But if I place the svg in front of the other elements, they can't be clicked.

I tried using:

```
pointer-events:none
```

But that also blocks mouse-move events, which I need.
So, my question is, is there any way I can allow mouse move events while still allowing interaction with other layered elements?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with a tweak to the javascript code.

Instead of attaching the event listener to the SVG element, I just attached it to the document; problem solved.